# Virtual Server in Apache causes 101 error

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I've set up (well, attempted to) Apache VHosting on my VPS. But I get the following error when I try to load any site from it now:

Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.

This is the config file which I added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName  photography.web.co.uk

        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/web.co.uk/htdocs/photography

        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/web.co.uk/cgi-bin/
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>


        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog  /var/www/web.co.uk/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/web.co.uk/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Is anyone able to identify what I have done wrong? There seem to be a couple of other people who had similar problems, but I really don't follow what the solution is saying.

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo netstat -tlnp` to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Location /cgi-bin>
   Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```

Get rid of this; it is unnecessary and should never be set in a Location anyway.

Comment: Thank you adaptr! So does the cgi-bin folder default to somewhere else then? Not that I'm using it right now, but were I to, I suppose it would be good to know where it's located!

Comment: This is what ScriptAlias **does**. Please read the section of the manual regairding ScriptAlias for a full explanation.